# Get data from URL with php/jquery

Tags: php, jquery, curl

I want to get data from an API. On my localhost server I can use the CURL method to get that data. But on the online webserver I can't use CURL because of "security reasons".

When I try file_get_contents it takes more than 30 seconds to get that data, which isn't normal I guess.

Are there any other methods of getting data from an API?

Url that I try getting data from: http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=1050

Answer (score 0):

maybe fopen:

```
function URLopen($url) 
{ 
    ini_set('user_agent','MSIE 4\.0b2;'); 
    $dh = fopen("$url",'r'); 
    $result = fread($dh,8192);                                                                                                                             
    return $result; 
} 
$returned=URLopen("http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=1050"); 

print_r(json_decode($returned));
```

Comment: Same problem as the file_get_contents: it takes more than 30 seconds to load :/

Comment: my host only 0.5 second, is rare

Comment: my localhost takes about 0.5s too, but on my webserver it takes 30 seconds+